# Is this website scrape-able with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would to scrape this website : https://www.projets-environnement.gouv.fr/pages/home/

More precisely, I would like to collect the table in the `div` with `id = table-wrapper`.

My trouble is that I can't catch it with `BeautifulSoup`.

Here is my code :

```
url = 'https://www.projets-environnement.gouv.fr/pages/home/'
html = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html5lib")
div_table = soup.findAll('div', id_='table-wrapper')
```

But `div_table` is a `None` object.
Is Selenium the solution ?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure there is a div with `id=table_wrapper` on the website?

Comment: Yes, just a little mistake, I edited the post from `id='table_wraper'` to `id='table-wrapper'`

Comment: When I check the website, I cannot find any div with `table-wrapper` nor with `table_wrapper`

Comment: I checked again and added a picture in the post.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? If the content you need is dynamically generated, then use Selenium, otherwise you can stick to Requests and BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use `selenium`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

url = 'https://www.projets-environnement.gouv.fr/pages/home/'

options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options)
driver.get(url)

html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
mytable = soup.find('div', id='table-wrapper')
```

and you get that table.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to call is:

```
soup.find("div", {"id": "table-wrapper"})
```